# How to access first n characters of a key value in Python

Tags: python, key, key-value

I need to access the first 10 characters of a key-value in dictionary. My dictionary looks like this:

```
data = {"id": "bob", "start_date": "2020-01-01 00:00:00"}
```

I have tried:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    new_start = data["start_date"][0,10]
```

The desired output is:

```
print new_start
2020-01-01
```

Comment: and what is the incorrect output you are getting ?

Comment: Why are you iterating over `data.items` when you aren't using `key` or `value` in the body of the loop?

Comment: Also instead of using the first 10 chars you could use `date['start_date'].split()[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a loop? You can do this directly:-

```
print(date['start_date'][0:10])
```

Output:-

```
'2020-01-01'
```